# How does the stick pusher prevent an aircraft from stalling?

Tags: stick-pusher

The stick shakers warns the pilot of stall conditions and some fixed winged aircraft have a stick pusher which tries to avoid the stall. What is the working methodology of stick pushers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [simple explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stick_pusher) is that a stick pusher is a:

> ... device that pushes forward on the elevator control system
>   whenever the aircraft’s angle of attack reaches the pre-determined
>   value, and then ceases to push when the angle of attack falls
>   sufficiently.

A [detailed explanation](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Stick_Pusher) is:

> A stick pusher system incorporates both a passive monitoring component
>   and an active intervention component that consists of an hydraulic or
>   electro-mechanical pusher mechanism. The monitoring component
>   constantly evaluates critical flight parameters such as airspeed, load
>   factor and flap setting against the aircraft angle of attack. If the
>   angle of attack reaches a predetermined value, the intervention
>   component of the system is activated and pushes forward on the
>   elevator control system until the angle of attack is reduced to an
>   acceptable value. The system operates autonomously and without any
>   required action by the pilots.

FAA has an [advisory circular (AC)](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1020244) for stick pusher training.

For Embraer 145, [this video](https://youtu.be/5GrwODV68R8) shows a demo of stick shaker, stick pusher and the warning systems.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate a bit on what the other answers say we must discuss what a stall is and how it happens.

First off ***a stall can happen at any speed or bank angle***

A stall by definition:

> ...is a reduction in the lift coefficient generated by a foil as angle of attack increases (see picture for what happens to the air when you stall)

[image]

and by definition a stall

> ...occurs when the critical angle of attack of the foil is exceeded

So in an aircraft the typical way to recover from a stall is to pitch the aircraft down. This helps to gain speed but mainly reduces the angle of attack of the wing (the angle you exceeded the limit of to stall in the first place) which in turn helps the wing regain proper air flow over it and begin to generate lift again. Thus a stick pusher servers to automate this function of pushing the stick forward (pitching the plane down) to recover from the stall. This can also help in situations where its difficult to know if the plane has stalled much like the accident that occurred on [Air France 447](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_Flight_447)

Comment: In the case of AF447 it is doubtful Bonin would have reacted any differently to a stick pusher than he did to the 75 loud "STALL" warnings which he ignored. If he didn't trust the audible "STALL" alerts, he probably wouldn't have trusted any other manifestations of the stall detection systems. Reading about [Bonin's actions](http://www.popularmechanics.com/flight/a3115/what-really-happened-aboard-air-france-447-6611877/) it seems to me unlikely a stick-pusher would have made much difference.

Comment: nb [Colgan AIr Flight 3407](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colgan_Air_Flight_3407) "As the aircraft came even closer to stalling **the stick pusher activated** ("The Q400 stick pusher applies an airplane-nose-down control column input to decrease the wing angle-of-attack [AOA] after an aerodynamic stall"). **The captain overrode the pusher and continued pulling on the control yoke causing the aircraft upset** and later loss of control."

Answer (score 2):

Regarding methodology here's how Douglas does it on the MD80.

> The stick pusher operates only with slats at mid or extend. It comes on 6 seconds after lights and horn or when AOA increases 4°. If auto slat has failed, stall lights and horn are 0.2 seconds after stick shaker, and the 6 second to override request only 2.5° of AOA for stick pusher.

[image: Stick Pusher Schematic]